# How to read current project path in .properties file

Tags: java, spring

I have abc.jks file under resources folder and i need to read that abc.jks file in test.properties file. How to read abc.jks file in test.properties file.

Answer (score 1):

In application.properties (or how you name it) assuming you use maven and you execute your spring application in the default project you can refer to the file like:

```
my.file.name = ./src/main/resources/abs.jks
```

or if this is for test purpose only you can put in the test resources and refer like this:

```
my.file.name = ./src/test/resources/abs.jks
```

For me the best is to not be dependent on folder and always use classloader resource, but if you have to refer a path on the filesystem, from java code you can do this:

```
URL url = getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("abs.jks");
File file = Paths.get(url.toURI()).toFile().getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: It will work even if this in a JAR, don't worry. URLs will be like file:///xxx.jar!/some/path/in/the/jar. Only Java understands them :), but they are still valid URLs.

Comment: I .. I absolutely don't know what I was thinking when I made that comment. You are of course correct, as is your answer. Pity I can't upvote it (again). Sorry for the noise.